# styleSheets & rules undefined in IE10

Tags: javascript, document, internet-explorer-10

I have this bit of javascript code I am trying to get to work in IE10. Been trying to use jquery to reference the styleSheet and the rule and initialize them. Hasn't helped. Here's the code:

```
    function SetBold(Item, bold) 
        {
        var aitemstyle = document.all.item(Item).style;

            if (aitemstyle) 
            {
                if (bold) 
                {
                    aitemstyle.fontWeight       = "bold";
                aitemstyle.color            = "black";
                    aitemstyle.textDecoration   = "none";
                }
                    //this else block of code causes function-expected error IE10 windows 8, oRule var initialization
                    else 
                    {
                    var oRule=document.styleSheets("panoramaCSS").rules("12pxHoverColorChange");
                //IE10 expected function from previous line. So, for loop below for finding 12pxHovercolorChange rule
                //inside panoramaCSS styleSheet
                //TODO make the selections off Panel Performance go unbold. Not working yet. 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `document.styleSheets` is no function, but a collection?

Comment: Do not use `document.all`!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it might be working in other browsers, but accessing a style-sheet and a rule requires square brackets:

```
var oRule=document.styleSheets("panoramaCSS").rules("12pxHoverColorChange");
```

shoud be

```
var oRule=document.styleSheets["panoramaCSS"].rules["12pxHoverColorChange"];
```

The reason for the error is that IE is interpreting the parentheses as a call to a function that doesn't exist.

This [quirksmode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html) should be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the square brackets. No dice. I was under the impression that if you use square brackets, you need to reference an array sub number, rather than a string. Maybe that's more java. I'll again.

Comment: document.styleSheets is an array of the styleSheets applied to the document.

Comment: rules returns an array of the rules from the styleSheet. So, I tried putting these arrays through a for loop to reference the correct sheet and rule as well. No dice yet. Thanks for the responses so far and any others appreciated!

Comment: I'll check out the quirksmode page. :)